# All-winners semifinals in tennis

Tags: trivia, tennis, history

At the 2018 US Open, the semifinals had three previous winners on the men's side.

Has it ever happened in a major tournament that all four places were held by previous winners?

If not, has it happened in any ATP tournament?

Answer (score 2):

Some other that came close :
**[2015 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)**. 3 were previous winners and 1 was a future (next year) winner
**[2012 Australian Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Australian_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)**. 3 were previous winners and the 4th was Murray who lost 2 finals before 2012 and 3 after
**[2011 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)**. 2 were previous winners, Djokovic won it that year and Murray the year after
**[2009 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)** was a unique one, in the SF were : 2008(Federer), 2009(Del Potro), 2010(Nadal) and 2011(Djokovic) champions
**[2008 US Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_US_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles)** had the same guys from 2011 (Big 4)

Comment: How about the women's?